# Count entity in Core Data with a specific Value

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, predicatebuilder

I have an Entity with some Attribute. I have my tabes already populates(SQLite table)
In one Attribute (i'll call Attribute1) i have a bool value, changing during use of my app.

How can i return the count of my Entities with Attribute1 value YES?

I've already read "Core data Tutorial" and "Predicate Programing Guide" but i don't understand how to proceed..

```
    NSPredicate *predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Attribute1 == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

I've tried with this, and then? it seems not working..

Answer (score 3):

The best bet is to use the countForFetchRequest method. Set up your predicate and fetch request, but instead of doing the actual fetch, execute countForFetchRequest as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

NSPredicate *predicate = 
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Attribute1 == %@",
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSUInteger count = [myManagedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

You can find more info in the Apple API Docs:

> countForFetchRequest:error:
>   Returns the number of objects a given fetch request would have returned if it had been passed to executeFetchRequest:error:.

- (NSUInteger)countForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error
  Parameters
  request
  A fetch request that specifies the search criteria for the fetch.
  error
  If there is a problem executing the fetch, upon return contains an instance of NSError that describes the problem.
  Return Value
  The number of objects a given fetch request would have returned if it had been passed to executeFetchRequest:error:, or NSNotFound if an error occurs.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
Declared In
NSManagedObjectContext.h